# bitbucket on my own server

Tags: software-rec, version-control, mercurial, repository

I want to have something like bitbucket.org or github (but for mercurial!) on my VDS. I don't need full functionality, but I need it being able to serve repositories, accept changes (with auth!) and creating new repos in one-two clicks in web interface. What can I use? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hgwebdir running in a web server (comes with mercurial) does everything except let you create the new repos with a click, which you can **very** easily do with a [simple script](http://ry4an.org/unblog/UnBlog/2009-09-17) you can put right in the hgwebdir footer.

Answer (score 1):

I have used bitbucket.org but I also wanted an in house DVCM server for my web development team, so we went with Redmine. This is tested and installed easy using BitNami images, http://bitnami.org/stack/redmine

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried it yet, but [RhodeCode](http://rhodecode.org/) seems to have all the features you'd ever want from a web based repository manager.

You can create new repositories, fork current repositories and it allows you to set up user authentication and access rights.

Answer (score 0):

If you have money, bitbucket has an hosted version (just ask Jesper for a quote).

Answer (score 0):

As described in the article  [Publishing Repositories](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories) in the mercurial wiki, mercurial has different way for publishing repositories (hg serve, ssh, hgwebdir, hgweb, ...).
Since you need multiple repositories with [push/pull authentication](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories#Allowing_Push) then you should go for [hgwebdir](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories#multiple) (also described [here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgWebDirStepByStep)).

After setting up hgwebdir, apart from pushing/pulling from the repositories, you will also have a web interface that will look like, for example, the [suckless.org code repository](http://hg.suckless.org/).

As [mentioned by Ry4an](https://superuser.com/questions/115365/bitbucket-on-my-own-server/116343#116343) you can't create a new repository via the web interface.

Answer (score 0):

For your needs you might want to take a look at [gitblit](http://gitblit.com/)
It is fairly basic and simple. It provides web-UI so you can manage as many repos as you need. However I found out that they don't have per branch permissions out of the box (requires some ground work with groovy scripts). On a flip side if it doesn't bother you, then it might be it!

Cheers mate!