# Simplest way to setup my own remote private git server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, virtual-machine, git

First of all, I've read all the git-server-setup documents on the internet, but still, there is one thing missing -- I want to setup a simple GIT server in (Ubuntu) Virtual Machine for myself, not for a team. I.e.,

**I'm trying to find the simplest way to setup my own private git server that don't need to depend on gitolite, gitweb, etc, etc. Just the plain simplest one.**

This article, https://askubuntu.com/questions/12647/setting-up-a-git-server, shows how to setup server-less git repository, but have to access it from remote via SSH:

```
git push ssh://<username>@<remote-git-hostname>/path/to/project.git master
```

That's very weird, not the common way,

```
git remote add origin git@git.droplet.com:my-project.git
```

The article I listed below, [How To Set Up a Private Git Server on a VPS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-private-git-server-on-a-vps) is very close to what I need, but miss the very important point. It shows how to setup `ssh user@123.45.56.78` but miss the important step for that user to use the form of `git@git.myown.com:my-project.git` to access git. E.g.,

```
git remote add origin git@git.droplet.com:my-project.git
```

So, again, **What's the simpliest way to setup a remote git server?**

Ref:

Articles read from this site:

- [How to setup own GIT Server? Whats bare/non-bare repos?](https://superuser.com/questions/276355/how-to-setup-own-git-server-whats-bare-non-bare-repos)
- [Setting up a private GIT Repo](https://superuser.com/questions/346462/setting-up-a-private-git-repo)
- [bitbucket on my own server](https://superuser.com/questions/115365/bitbucket-on-my-own-server)

Others:

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-private-git-server-on-a-vps
- http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server

Comment: You've missed the point entirely. difference between using an ip address or a domain has never been my concern.

Comment: The tutorial clearly shows how to set up the Git user (`useradd git` etc.) to store the projects under.

Comment: The tutorial clearly shows how to do `useradd git`, but beyond that, e.g., how to use the form of `git@git.myown.com:my-project.git` to access git is still missing. I meant, no ssh access to that `git` user setup is mentioned, which is the most important step.

Comment: Do you have an SSH server installed and running? Can other users log in? Then a `git` user should also be able to log in.

Comment: You mean to upload my id_rsa.pub file to that `git` user's home directory, so that I can ssh in as `git@gitserver`. hmm... OK. I'll try. Anything else?

Comment: That should be enough to give you access. Not sure if there's anything to consider after that, but as long as you can log in with the `git` user, the rest should be easy.